# "los dos de usted" or "los dos de ustedes": Which one is correct?

Tags: traducción, pronombres

How can I translate "The two of you"?

> Los dos de usted
>
> Los dos de ustedes

According to Google Translate (GT), either of these can be used. However, I do not completely trust GT.

"Los dos de ustedes" seems proper to me.

However, "los dos de usted" does not seem to be proper because "los dos" is plural while "usted" is singular.

Is one or both of these proper Spanish?

Example usage:

> The two of you speak Spanish with different accents.
>
> Los dos de usted(es) hablan español con diferentes acentos.

Comment: "Ambos" or "ustedes vos" should suffice. However, try showing an example because it may change depending on the context.

Comment: Thanks @fedorqui, I've updated the question to have an example.

Comment: Más que traducir lo que piden explicad de paso que con "Dos de ustedes" equivale intuitivamente a Both of you. Y no hay que confundirlo con "You both".
Fedorqui tiene razón.
To me, the more idiomatic way to translate it is to use Ustedes dos.
Fedorqui is right. Punto pelota. Dot ball.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both "los dos de usted" and "los dos de ustedes" do not make much sense. "los dos de usted" is even gramatically incorrect, since "usted" should be plural, as you mention in the question.

To me, the more idiomatic way to translate it is to use **Ustedes dos**.

> The two of you speak Spanish with different accents.

is

> Ustedes dos hablan español con diferentes acentos.

And, depending on the case, you can even omit the "dos" because it is obvious. For example, if you are talking with these two people and no other person is around.

Comment: For my own clarification - it's not "Ustedes dos hablan espanol con acentos diferentes." because that would mean the accents have some intrinsic property making them different? (Can't figure out how to say that)...kind of like how it's "Tengo un coche rojo" instead of "Tengo un rojo coche", since the car is itself red?  Where with accents, there's nothing intrinsic making them different - only when comparing them is there.  (Does this question make sense?)

Comment: "Ustedes dos hablan con *acentos diferentes*" means that they are using at least two different accents, so it is implicit that it is not the same for both of them. "Ustedes dos hablan con [un] *acento diferente*" means that the people refered are using a *single, common* accent (assumed to be different to the speaker accent, or the accent of someone else previously implied). In fact, this would apply either for "dos" or for any number.

Answer (score 0):

No, fedorqui... While you normally *would* be correct, it would depend on what you are actually trying to say. "Los dos de ustedes" *could* make perfect sense.

By the way... I congratulate you on not trusting GT. It makes a translation job that is good enough for humans to understand, but makes horrible use of grammar and sometimes vocabulary. Sometimes, when it can actually not figure out what you are trying to say, it actually leaves your original text (or some of it) untranslated.

Now,when would you be incorrect?

Assume you where trying to say: The two [*representatives*] from you. If the word representatives is clear enough from context, said form is correct.

Granted:

1. This is not what you would normally said in everyday usage.
2. The example I have given is only that,a quick example. You could construct other sentences with context derived words where that form would be correct.

Comment: "Los dos de ustedes"  podría ser correcto pero NO en el sentido del la frase en inglés "The two of you" la cual se debe traducir como "ustedes dos". Como tu dices "los dos de ustedes" puede ser correcta pero si hubiera un sujeto implícito/tácito pero la pregunta no se trata de si "los dos de ustedes" es correcto o no sino de como se dice en español "the two of you"

Answer (score 0):

GT toma ambas opciones válidas ya que está interpretando la frase original en español como posesión, o sea "los dos elementos que le pertenece(n) a usted(es)".

Como el inglés perdió la diferencia entre 2ª persona singular y plural, ambas frases en español dan la misma traducción al inglés.

En cuanto a la pregunta: "Los dos de usted" es incorrecta, "Los dos de ustedes" es correcta, pero no suena natural, "Ustedes dos" es correcta y suena natural.

Por último, con "Ustedes" ya alcanza para referirse a un grupo de personas, salvo que la idea aquí sea llamar la atención de un subgrupo del mismo.